# Compare genetic programming performance

Tags: statistics, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I've run 30 * 7 runs of a genetic program on a dataset, 30 runs of 7 different parameter settings, now, I'd like to compare the results.
Each program ran for 200 generations
I've gathered data from every generation but what I'd like to compare was the best test  fitness of the 30 runs with all other 30 runs from every setting to check if there is a difference between the results of the different parameters.
Due to the nature of the thing, the distribution isnt normal, so I was thinking in running a Kruskal Wallis test on the 7 data columns (each column with 30 samples) .

What do you guys think ?

Thanks
Jorge

Answer (score 0):

How do you define performance?
Assuming you mean convergence to an optimum (or at least to a local extreme), you may want to compare:

1. Optima achieved in each run
2. The rate at which you achieved them (average increments or something similar).

For the 2. point you may even want to fit in a curve (e.g. line) and try to compare a<sub>i</sub> parameters in y<sub>i</sub>=a<sub>i</sub>x+b<sub>i</sub>

Looking only on the statistical side you could also use [Wilcoxon rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) since you can group the runs in pairs.

And by the way, since each run with a given set of parameters (at least theoretically) may give you slightly different results (due to the inherent random nature of genetic programming) you may want to have at least a few runs per each set of parameters you want to tune to eliminate a (mis?)fortunate influence of randomness.

Comment: it is a minimization problem the closer to 0 the better. i have 30 runs with each parameter setting.

Comment: So first of all you may want to compare if the runs were getting close to 0  (with some "epsilon" tolerance). Then you could check the speed of convergence.

Comment: I already have some grphical analisys of the runs and so on, what Id like is some quantitative method of telling me how different are the methods results, so I could measure if is there a point in using mehod A or B.
There are 7 different algorithms 'competing'.

Comment: I don't think a paired-Wilcoxon is the right way to go since there are not meaningful pairs in the runs (certainly not relevant to the study.)  In general, since there are seven treatments, if any Wilconxon were done, you'd also need to control for multiple comparisons, which Kruskal-Wallis accounts for naturally.